# Lost letter, base conversion

Tags: python, radix

I am trying to do a custom base conversion in Python by converting from base 39 to base 10 and back. It works fine, except that I lose the last letter of my string:

```
#base 39(custom characters)
chars = 'esiarntolcdugpmhbyfvkwzxjq 0.,123456789'
nchars = len(chars)

#text that is converted (I am not bob btw)
text = 'hello everyone, bob here'

#convert to decimal 
final = 0
for i, v in enumerate(text):
    print(v)
    final += nchars**i * chars.index(v)

text1 = ''
ind = 0
#convert back to custom base
while final >= 1:
    print(final)
    text1 += chars[final % nchars]
    final = final // nchars

print(text1)
# prints hello everyone, bob her
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You’re using integer division in this line, `final // nchars`, I wonder if this is causing an issue ... ?  Debug this line a bit further to test.

Comment: Note that you are writing your number in reverse order: units as first digit, then number of 39, of 39**2....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't systematically lose the last letter of `text`, this actually only ever happens when it ends with the letter "e". So what's special about that particular letter? Well it starts (or, should I say, it is at index `0` of) your encoding dictionary, `chars`. Therefore, what would the encoded value of `'e'` be? What `final` value would that represent and what impact would that have on your decoding loop's condition?

I believe this is enough for you to find your bug. However, next time, try using a debugger and step through the code; you'll be able to see where the issue comes from.